# Can I continue using MongoDB v2.2.0rc using the 1.6.4 Ruby driver?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, nosql

The latest release candidate for MongoDB 2.2 has been released. There doesn't seem to be a newer version of the Ruby driver for MongoDB. Will Ruby driver 1.6.4 continue to functions okay under MongoDB 2.2.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hate to say this, but the answer is: maybe, it depends on what you want to do with it.

If you take a look at the 1.7.0 notes you will see that several of the fixes currently in the pipeline are to do with supporting new features in 2.2 (like the aggregation framework and read preferences):

https://jira.mongodb.org/secure/ReleaseNote.jspa?projectId=10005&version=11154

So, 1.7.0 will be the release that will allow you to use the new features, but the 1.6.4 version should still work as long as those are not on your "must have" list at the moment.  The developers always try, within reason, to avoid the kind of backward breaking issues that make driver versions incompatible.  That being said, there are a list of backward breaking changes in the 2.2 release listed here:

https://jira.mongodb.org/secure/IssueNavigator.jspa?requestId=11225

Have a read through those, see if any of them apply to your usage.  The rest of the release notes can be found here:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/2.2/

Finally, once the driver (or a release candidate) is ready, you will see an announcement on the [mongodb-announce](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/mongodb-announce) user group